# Is this a bad first post audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, first-post-review

I've just [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16153697) in the first post queue. Which annoyingly has resulted in my being review banned (no complaints, it's there for a reason).

And while the answer is low quality, I would argue that the answer is not *very* low quality:

> Change the id of the form u have the same id for the each form. (1 downvote)

It does attempt to answer the question. It could do with some spelling changes etc (I deserve to fail the audit since I at least should've downvoted).  Another answer for the same question has nigh the same content and instead received an upvote:

> Two forms with the same id="form" --> error. Rename one of the forms. (1 upvote)

I recall from attempting (and failing) to flag questions as VLQ for poor answers before that:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

For those reasons I would argue that this is not a VLQ answer (although editting was needed), and without further investigation it is not a duplicate answer (and you can't flag answers as duplicate).

**So**, although I deserve the temp ban hammer for at least failing to down vote/edit in the audit, is this really a VLQ answer or is it a poor audit?

Comment: You *can't* downvote from the VLQ queue.  It's not what the queue is for.  It's for deleting content that's not even a bad answer (let alone a good one).

Comment: It would appear that the answer was deleted because it's just duplicating another answer posted several years before, not because of poor English or a lackluster explanation (that's certainly the only defensible argument that I can see anyway).

Comment: @Servy Sorry this is the First Post queue

Comment: In that case yes, you unquestionably deserved to fail the audit.

Comment: @Servy absolutely, I'm asking if it really is VLQ though

Comment: Probably, but it's a perfectly fine audit even if you don't think that it is.  The post is still unquestionably bad, and needs to be acted on in *some* way, even if you disagree over *what* way, so anyone that says that it needs no action from the queue is doing something wrong, and the audit would succeed in catching that.

Comment: *Sorry this is the First Post queue* - Could you edit the body of the post so it's clear? ryanyuyu fixed the title but the body still talks about VLQ so it's kind of confusing.

Comment: @BSMP I think it's possible that this is the source of confusion.  VLQ review and First Post review are distinct queues with different goals and rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible you are mixing up the [VLQ queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) and the [First Post queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats). They are are distinct queues with different goals and rules.  Some notable differences:

First Posts:

- The goal is to educate new users about SO posting standards.
- This queue is fed automatically whenever a new user makes their first post.  This includes both questions and answers.
- It requires only 500 reputation to access this review queue.
- There are a myriad of ways to address posts, including normal post interactions (voting, commenting etc). Voting is more expected, including upvoting good first posts.
- Commenting is considered a review action to audits, so you can fail/pass audits by commenting.

Low Quality Posts (aka VLQ):

- The goal is to remove egregiously bad content.
- This queue is fed when posts receive various kinds of flags (NAA, VLQ).  Recently, this queue focuses only on answers.
- It requires 3k reputation to access this review queue.
- For the most part, reviews are binary: this is VLQ and needs to be deleted, or this is not bad enough to warrant deletion.
- Comments can give the poster a small window of time to reform their answer into a suitable answer, especially summarizing relevant content from a link-only answer.  They are not part of the review audits.

Specifically to your situation, the audit you came across is a fine audit.  That answer has various issues with it.  At the very least, comments/downvotes for its poor formatting are necessary to educate the new user of our posting standards.  And as you admit, you have no complaints with the outcome of the audit.  You are correct that this does not qualify for VLQ flagging, but that's not important within the context of the First Post review queue.  This is a good example of a typical First Post review that needs fixing.  **The audit is fair and unambiguous.**

Comment: *"You are correct that this does not qualify for VLQ flagging, but that's not important within the context of the First Post review queue"* - This is what I was looking for